# See the code of a graph that is already created

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I have a graph in Excel and want to use the exact format, size, axes, title etc. I know that I can just record a macro of me recreating a similar graph, but is there a way to step into the code of the one already created?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the existing code. You'll have to adjust some of the hard-coded parts of the code, since the data range and the chart object name of the new chart will be different.

If you post the recorded code, someone might be able to help with this.